# expecting type error when extending and generic class

Tags: typescript

I think I should get more type errors when I instantiate generic
class, then extend it, then overwrite an instance field in an
inconsistent way.  The code:

```
class Abs<T> {
    public f(v: T) : string {
        return "";
    }
}

class Imp extends Abs<{s: string}> {
    public f(v) {
        return v.noSuchField;  // should be: 'return v.s'!
   }
}
```

It appears that the type inferred for argument `v` in `new Imp().f` is
`any`, not `{s: string}`.

I would have expected one of two things to happen here:

1. A type error because the argument of `Imp.f` does not have a subtype
   of `{s: string}`.
2. A type error because `Imp.f` is typed `{s: string}` as expected, but
   this type does not contain a string-typed field `noSuchField`.

...  and I have two questions:

1. Would any of you agree that this is a bug in typescript?
2. Is there a way to do this that give me the expected type error
   ('no such field: `noSuchField`')?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not a bug.

On the first point - an error because of the type of `Imp.f::v` doesn't exactly match its base type, is not an error in any standard OO language. `Imp.f` is a *more general* function in terms of its arguments than its base class, because `any` is a more general parameter than `{s: string}`. You can be a subclass of a base class when your arguments are more general than the base implementation's. For example, in C#, this is not an error:

```
class Foo {
    public void x(FileStream s) { }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    // Not an error, even though Bar.x:s is a more general type than Foo.x:s
    public void x(Stream s) { }
}
```

On the second, on not getting an error about `v.noSuchField`, it's the expected behavior because `v` is of type `any`. Whenever you have an expression of type `any`, you're basically never going to get a type error because of that expression.

Note that a type is never "inferred" for a parameter of a class member function declaration. `v` is `any` (the default type) because it lacks a type annotation.

You can cause this code to have an error by compiling with the `--noImplicitAny` flag, which will cause the implicitly-any type of `v` to be an error. Once you add some type annotation (other than `any`, of course), you'll then get an error on `v.noSuchField`.